# NHibernate Get & string Id

Tags: string, nhibernate, case-sensitive

I've an entity with assigned string Id on NHibernate and I've a little problem when get an entity by Id.

Example...

Suppose that have a database record like this...

```
Id    Description
-------------------
AAA   MyDescription
```

now, if I use "Get" method using search id "aaa"...

```
MYENTITYTYPE entity = Session.Get<MYENTITYTYPE>("aaa")
```

return right entity but Id field (entity.Id) is "aaa", while I wish it were equal to "AAA".

In summary I would like that "Get" method return the id identical to the one stored in the database...with the same case.

Is possible? How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. My guess is that it's not possible, because the Id might exist **before** the DB call. Consider the following:

```
var foo = session.Load<Foo>("aaa"); //no DB call, foo is a proxy
Console.WriteLine(foo.Id); //Prints "aaa";
var bar = foo.Bar; //Forces loading
Console.WriteLine(foo.Id); //No matter what, the Id can't change at this point
```

This illustrates another reason why primary keys with meaning are usually a bad idea, especially if their input is not controlled.

Now, if instead of `Get` you use a query, you will get the right-cased Id:

```
//example with LINQ; you can use HQL, Criteria, etc
var foo = session.Query<Foo>().Single(x => x.Id == "aaa");
```

The drawback is that you will always go to the DB, even if the entity is already loaded.

Now, if you defined your entity as **{Id, Code, Description}**, where `Id` is a synthetic POID (I recommend **Hilo** or **Guid**) and `Code` is the existing string Id, you will avoid potential bugs caused by using `Get` instead of a query with the code.

Comment: I know, unfortunately this is due to the use of legacy db :( So, I tried to use ICriteria in this way: Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(MYENTITYTYPE)).Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", "aaa")).UniqueResult<MYENTITYTYPE>() and it works. My doubt is this also works for "composite-id" like Get. What do you think?

Comment: Queries will always work as described above. If you're using a separate class for a composite id, you *might* have to query field by field (not necessarily; this is just a wild guess on how to fix a potential issue)

Comment: I tried the same statement with a composite-Id class and seems to work, also without set an "Eq" for each property. I've overridden "GetHashCode" and "Equals" methods, but I'm not sure that's enough.

Comment: Glad to know it works, then. Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem.