# Protected Variables and model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Please see the models below:

```
public class Apple //: Fruit
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; protected  set; }
    }

    public class AppleModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

and the controller below:

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(Apple apple)
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var AppleModel = new AppleModel();
                AppleModel.Id = 1;
                AppleModel.Description = "Apple";
                var Apple = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Apple>(AppleModel);
                return View("View1",Apple);
            }
```

and the view below:

```
    @model PreQualification.Web.Controllers.Apple

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "View1";
    }

    <h2>View1</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>AppleModel</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

Apple.Id is 0 in the HttpPost method because it is a protected variable in the model.  Is there anyway around this?

The reason I ask is because I am trying to use this as a model: https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/tree/master/source/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity and the id contained in the superclass is protected.

Comment: @David, I have updated my post.  Sorry.

Comment: Why aren't you using `AppleModel` in Post method as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways around this, including a child class that implements a public whose setter applies the value to the protected id field.

However these are bandaids. Generally these problems are encountered because of a difference in how people view models. Either it is a reusable Data Transfer Object or it is not.

In the world where it is not, you have to shoehorn business objects into bindable models and always run into these weird problems.

In the world where they are, they are custom tailored to fit the data needs and are mapped into business objects with something like an automapper. More importantly, by making a model to fit this request, you protect against attacks on accidentally exposed parameters.

If the makeshift business object has public properties that change your behavior, they can be exploited by sending additional parameters back with the post request.

I know this does not specifically answer your question, but following the path where models are not DTO's is probably not the right answer either.

Answer (score 0):

As elaborated by peewee_RotA, it's better to separate out the conceptual differences between a model used for a view and a domain model that will actually perform an action or is used to directly perform an action. To that end, you need a view model such as `Apple`

```
public class Apple
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

In your post action, you'd have;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Apple apple)
{
    // translate your view model to your domain model
    AppleModel model = new AppleModel(apple.Id, apple.Description);
    model.DoStuff();
}
```

In terms of NHiberhate though, it's not easy to instantiate the required object with the view model's ID and this is the crux of your issue I think. You're trying to use your domain model as a view model and the domain model is locked down...legitimately. It's job is to control how `IdentityUser` and the like are instantiated as they're meant to be generated by the associated factory classes, not MVC's model binder.

To that end, leave your view model as simple as possible and leverage NHibernate's factory classes to create the necessary `Identity` objects by looking up the ID. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21325367/1838819) link may shed some light on how to look up the user ID passed in by `Apple.Id`.

**EDIT**

I've done a little more digging on looking up the entity in NHibernate and the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10785884/1838819) post seems to do the basics. Does this get what you need?